# How to use directive to remove el-table-column of elementUI in vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, directive, element-ui

```
function install (Vue, options = {}) {
  Vue.directive(options.name || 'auth', {
    async inserted (el, binding, vNode) {
      if (!await checkPermission(binding.value)) {
        el.parentNode && el.parentNode.removeChild(el)
      }
    },
  })
}

<el-table>
      <el-table-column
        v-auth=""code""
        label="label"
        prop="xx"
      >
</el-tabl>
```

I want to show/hide the column dynamic with a custom directive, but it doesn't work, why?

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem.

What I did to solve the issue was to show/hide the column with a v-if sentence and a computed property, but it will be good if we can achieve the same result using Vue directives.

Hope it helps.